# Wait for a request in axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want to run two POSTs requests, the first one gives me some information needed for the second one. I'm running something like this:

```js
axios(config).then((function(response: any) {
            const data = JSON.parse(response);
            const info = data.info;
        }).finally(function() {
            // Second request
            const final = `${info} and final`;
            // This is supposed to be just another valid axios request
            conf = final;
            axios(final)
        });
```

First of all that JSON.parse is not working as I would expect, I though we could access the info of the response, just with that `JSON.parse` and then `.<field>` but it's not working for me.

Also, the use of finally to be sure that the first request has finished is correct, or it is not?

Answer (score 1):

> First of all that JSON.parse is not working as I would expect

See [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema).

`response` is **not** a string of JSON.

It is an object. The response body is available through the `data` property. If the body is JSON, it will be parsed automatically and the result assigned to `data`.

> Also, the use of finally to be sure that the first request has finished is correct, or it is not?

No. `finally` runs when the promise is settled — no matter if it was successful or not.

You almost certainly don't want to be carrying on if there was an error so you should be using `then`.

Do everything in your existing `then` callback.